# Установка соединения с помощью сокета для веб-протокола

Tags: веб-программирование, сокет, c++, visual-studio

Пытаюсь реализовать на с++ Sokcet для web протокола, а точнее пока ограничивается только функцией `MakeConnection2`, которая должна конектиться к переданному ей адресу по 80 порту. Текст программы прилагается внизу. Но при компиляции возникают ошибки:

```
HTTPMain.obj : error LNK2019: ссылка на неразрешенный внешний символ _connect@12 в функции "int __cdecl MakeConnection2(char *)" (?MakeConnection2@@YAHPAD@Z)
1>HTTPSocket.obj : error LNK2001: неразрешенный внешний символ "_connect@12"
1>HTTPMain.obj : error LNK2019: ссылка на неразрешенный внешний символ _socket@12 в функции "int __cdecl MakeConnection2(char *)" (?MakeConnection2@@YAHPAD@Z)
1>HTTPSocket.obj : error LNK2001: неразрешенный внешний символ "_socket@12"
1>HTTPMain.obj : error LNK2019: ссылка на неразрешенный внешний символ _htons@4 в функции "int __cdecl MakeConnection2(char *)" (?MakeConnection2@@YAHPAD@Z)
1>HTTPSocket.obj : error LNK2001: неразрешенный внешний символ "_htons@4"
1>HTTPMain.obj : error LNK2019: ссылка на неразрешенный внешний символ _gethostbyname@4 в функции "int __cdecl MakeConnection2(char *)" (?MakeConnection2@@YAHPAD@Z)
1>HTTPSocket.obj : error LNK2001: неразрешенный внешний символ "_gethostbyname@4"
1>C:\Users\Владимир\Documents\Visual Studio 2008\Projects\HTTPSocet\Debug\HTTPSocet.exe : fatal error LNK1120: 4 неразрешенных внешних элементов
========== Построение: успешно: 0, с ошибками: 1, без изменений: 0, пропущено: 0
```

Подскажите, пожалуйста в чём, проблема? Из-за чего возникают эти ошибки? Как это исправить? Пишу в IDE VisualStudio2010.
Код программы:

```
#include "stdafx.h"
 #include <iostream>
    #include <windows.h>
    #include <winsock.h>
    using namespace std;
    int MakeConnection2( char* ServerName);
    int MakeConnection2( char* ServerName){
      int s;
      struct sockaddr_in ssin;
      struct hostent* hp;
      int PortNum;
      int Namber=strlen((const char*)ServerName);
      unsigned char * strHlp=new unsigned char(Namber);
      char  *pch;

      /* use default port number - 80 or specific number from the
         server name */
      strcpy((char *)strHlp,(const char *)ServerName);
      pch = strchr( (char*)strHlp,':');
      if(pch==NULL){
        PortNum = 80;
      }else{
        pch[0] = '\0';
        pch++;
        PortNum = atoi(pch);
        if(PortNum==0){
          PortNum = 80;
        }
      }

      /* get host by name - resolve host name into IP address */
      if( (hp=gethostbyname((const char*)strHlp)) == NULL  )
      {
         return -1;
      }

      memset((&ssin), '\0', sizeof(ssin));
      memmove((hp->h_addr), (&ssin.sin_addr), hp->h_length);
      ssin.sin_family = hp->h_addrtype;
      ssin.sin_port = htons(PortNum);

      /* allocate a socket */
      if((s=socket(AF_INET, SOCK_STREAM, 0))==-1)
      {
         return -1;
      }

      /* make a connection */
      int t=connect(s, (const sockaddr*)&ssin, sizeof(ssin));
      if(t==-1){

         return -1;
      }

      return s; /* socket descriptor */
    }

    int main()
    {char b[]={'y','a','.','r','u',':','8','0'};
        int t=MakeConnection2((char*)b);
        return 0;
    }
```

Comment: Не указаны библиотеки для линковки. Что и где указать   VisualStudio2010 не знаю, а в MinGW gcc ... -lws2_32 -lwsock32

Comment: жаль мне для VisualStudio2010 нужно, а MinGW gcc у меня нету

Comment: @sch345, Вы посмотрите в Help-ах наверняка есть, как подключать библиатеки. Сами .dll лежат в windows\\system32

Answer (score 1):

```
#include <winsock2.h>
#pragma comment(lib, "Ws2_32.lib")
```

Answer (score 0):

Наизусть не помню, но может быть причина в следующем: в windows.h вроде как "инклудится" winsock.h - попробуйте сделать проверку на подключение хедера (#ifdef...), и еще, существует-же winsock2.h.

Comment: Проверил похоже winsock.h действительно инклюдится в windows.h, но не смотря на то что я закоментил инклюд winsock.h, ошибки так и остались притом теже самые:( А не подскажите какой нибудь рускоязычный материал по winsock2.h ?

Comment: Посмотрите здесь http://citforum.ru/book/cook/winsock.shtml, а вообще - любой поисковик и вперед (MSDN тоже не отменяли). И кстати, что Вы закоментили? Проверку на подключение хедера необходимо делать директивой #ifdef.